# A JS function that is a near replica of a working JS function does not work

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, codeigniter

I am using the below function to grab a JSON file from an API.

```
public function searchPokemon($pokemon)
{
    $pokemon = strtolower($pokemon);
    $pokesiteaddressAPI = "http://pokeapi.co/api/v1/pokemon/" . $pokemon . "/";
    $pokemondata = file_get_contents($pokesiteaddressAPI);

    $this->load->view('pages/pokemon', json_decode($pokemondata));
}
```

This function works totally fine, and is called correctly from the View, and passes data correctly back into it.

However, this very similar function;

```
public function searchMove($move)
{
    $movesiteaddressAPI = "http://pokeapi.co/api/v1/move/" . $move . "/";
    $movedata = file_get_contents($movesiteaddressAPI);

    $this->load->view('pages/move', json_decode($movedata));
}
```

Not only does this not work, it simply refuses to return anything to the page, including any error messages.

They are both called from this JS Script in the View.

```
<script>
    function SearchPokemon()
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url:"http://mi-linux.wlv.ac.uk/~1009780/CodeIgniter/index.php/search/searchPokemon/" + $("#pokemon").val(),
            success:function(pokemonresult){
                $("#poke").html(pokemonresult);
            }
        });
    }

    function SearchMove()
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url:"http://mi-linux.wlv.ac.uk/~1009780/CodeIgniter/index.php/search/searchMove/" + $("#move").val(),
            success:function(moveresult){
                $("#move").html(moveresult);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Can anyon e see why the Pokemon search would work, but the Move search would not? Pokemon can take a value of 1 - however many Pokemon there are or the Pokemon name, but Move can only take a numerical value, as the API is not fully functional yet.

Thank you.

EDIT: Following the URL of http://mi-linux.wlv.ac.uk/~1009780/CodeIgniter/index.php/search/searchMove/2 shows me that the information is actually being found, but not returned to the View correctly.

Comment: var_dump or print_r the $movedata to see what structure do you get.

Comment: Where about would I do that, in the View or the Controller?

Comment: Function in Controller now looks like `public function searchMove($move)
 {
  $movesiteaddressAPI = "http://pokeapi.co/api/v1/move/" . $move . "/";
  $movedata = file_get_contents($movesiteaddressAPI);

  $this->load->view('pages/move', json_decode($movedata));
  print_r($movedata)
 }` but nothing is outputting still.

Comment: I forgot the `;` at the ned of the `print_r` line. It outputs the JSON file (`{"accuracy": 100, "category": "", "created": "2013-11-03T15:06:09.500246", "description": "Inflicts regular damage. Has a 10% chance to burn the target.", "id": 7, "modified": "2013-12-24T15:24:29.681811", "name": "Fire-punch", "power": 75, "pp": 15, "resource_uri": "/api/v1/move/7/"}`) correctly.

Comment: $data['movedata']=json_decode($movedata);
$this->load->view('pages/move', $data);

In your pages/move view you can access the results in this style $movedata['accuracy'] or whatever key you want

Comment: So why can't I pass $movedata as $movedata, why do I have to set it into $data to pass? I dont have to with $pokemondata.

Comment: As i can tell you are using codeigniter, right?
How were you trying to access the values in your view, without assigning them all under an array? just by echoing the key? e.g. echo $accuracy?

Comment: Yep, thats exactly how, and for the Pokemon search it worked just fine.

Comment: i just told you to do because it is better structured, that's the only reason. A i can see in the url you are providing it is working , right? I can see the results

Comment: Its meant to be bringing it back into this page (http://mi-linux.wlv.ac.uk/~1009780/CodeIgniter/index.php/pages/view/home) using AJAX.

Comment: as i see in your html, you have <input type="text" name="move" /> and in your js you are useing $('#move).val(). So you forgot to put an id in the input thats why you dont get anything. Also as i can tell hte api you are using , needs a move id, not a move name, in order to bring results. So you should probably create an ajax dropdown with the moves of the current pokemon you get, based on the result. Right now if you put an id in your move search box (if you already asigned an id="move" on it) it is working fine and returns the view with the move in the response

Comment: So thats my `<input type="text" id="move" name="move" />` line that is incorrect? I'm not worried about creating a drop down just yet, but when I input a number such as 1 or 7 (both of which are valid entreis for this API), still nothing is returned. What exactly do I need to change to just get the search by ID number working? Sorry if I am being a bit slow on the uptake here.

Comment: I literally just realised what you meant. Is having my input box and output <div> being set to the same ID confusing things?

Comment: Now it is OK, the first time i cheched you were missing the id. Now it is fine I just trying to figure out why $("#move").html(moveresult); isn't working. Remove the print_r you dont need it :P

Comment: It was. When I renamed my output <div> to moves, and set the function to write back to there, it began to work. If you want to sum up what you said as an answer, ill mark it as correct. Thank you very much,

Comment: That was so small and i got it all the hard way :P the only problem was the id missing, but checked just now the html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were missing the input id in your html

```
<input id="move" name="move" type="text" />
```